# Make installshield merge module installation path configurable for user

Tags: installshield, merge-module

I have 2 custom installshield merge modules. I am using these merge modules inside a installshield project. Now I want when user run main installshield package then he should be able to select the installation path of 2 merge modules him self. Is it possible in installshield merge module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create 2 features in the installshield project, with 1 merge module in each feature. Then make sure the Custom Destination dialog is in your sequence, so the user can select the install path for each feature.